# Integrating two diff dataframes using contains condition and creating a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First data frame looks like below:

```
OSIED  geometry
257005 POLYGON ((311852.712 178933.993, 312106.023 17...
017049 POLYGON ((272943.107 137755.159, 272647.627 13...
017032 POLYGON ((276637.425 146141.397, 276601.509 14...
```

Second data frame looks like below:

```
small_area                                                   Median_BER
217099001/217112002/217112003/2570052005/217112...            212.9
047041005/047041001/2570051004/047041002/047041...            271.3
157041002/157041004/157041003/157041001/157129...            222.5
```

I need to search col1(df1) in col1(df2) using "contains" condition.
If it matches/has the string then fetch the corresponding values from df1 and df2

I tried merge,df.get and str.contains.
str.contains works but I am unable to fetch other records

Output should look like this:

```
OSIED  geometry                                            small_area                                     Median_BER
257005 POLYGON ((311852.712 178933.993, 312106.023 17...  217099001/217112002/217112003/2570052005/217112
212.9
017049 POLYGON ((272943.107 137755.159, 272647.627 13...  047041005/047041001/2570051004/047041002/047041
222.5
```

Comment: how big are the dataframes? If relatively small, then one could create primary keys to join the two tables - firstly by splitting the small_area and selecting the first 6d digits etc.

Comment: its a huge dataframe with 20k records

Comment: <insert Crocodile Dundee ref> "that's not a huge dataframe". how many unique small area codes in total from the slash sep rows?

Comment: df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['small_area','OSIED','geometry','Median_BER'])
for index, row in sf.iterrows():
    df3 = berdata[berdata['small_area'].str.contains("25700")==True]
    #print ("Helloworld")
    df3.append(row['OSIED'])
    df3.append(row['geometry'])
    print (df3)
    break

Comment: I am able to get the area code and median_BER from the above code..how do I fetch the geonetry and oseid col values

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with some code I was able to generate the following

```
small_area_oseid_df = pd.DataFrame(
   [
     {'OSIED': oseid[:6], 'median_ber': row['median_ber']} 
     for row in df.to_dict(orient='records') 
     for oseid in row['small_area'].split('/')
    ] 
)
```

Then you can join this table with the first table on the `OSIED` key. This is dependent on how many elements are in each row in the split. Since this will explode the dimension for the `small_area_oseid_df` you will create.